# Multiplying every Nth element in a list by M

Tags: python, list

I have a problem I can't seem to figure out.  I am very new to Python and have only been coding for three weeks.  Any help is appreciated.

## Problem:

We are passing in 3 inputs:

- a list of numbers
- a multiplier value, M
- a value, N

> You should multiply every Nth element (do not multiply the 0th element) by M. So if N is 3, you start with the 3rd element, which is index 2.
>
> If there are less than N elements then you should output the unchanged input list.

I can't seem to figure this out.  I have tried many different things here. Currently, I have the following, which is not working at all.

## Provided:

```
import sys
M= int(sys.argv[2])
N= int(sys.argv[3])

numbers= sys.argv[1].split(',')
for i in range(0, len(numbers)):
  numbers[i]= int(numbers[i])
```

## My Code:

```
for N in numbers:
    if numbers[i] > 0:
    total = N * M
    print(total)
else:
    print(numbers)
```

## Output:

I am not even close to what the output should be. Feeling lost on this. Here is what my code comes to. It looks like they want the output in a list.

```
Program Failed for Input: 1,2,3,4,5,6 5 3
Expected Output: [1, 2, 15, 4, 5, 30]
Your Program Output:
5
10
15
20
25
30
```

Comment: Thank you for assisting me with my question, Martineau. I am new to this site and to coding in general, so I appreciate the help. I have really enjoyed this site and the community seems to be very friendly, welcoming, and helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You could try a list comprehension with slicing.

```
numbers[N-1::N] = [x * M for x in numbers[N-1::N]]
```

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant solution using list comprehensions ;)

```
[item*M if (index and not (index+1)%N) else item for index, item in enumerate(items)]
```

[image]

Comment: The SS was for showing an execution example, the text answer is just above.

Comment: The fact that you have not noticed does not mean that it was not there. If you check the edit history the SS was uploaded after the text response.

Comment: Done :) thanks for the time of answer and sorry if I sounded a little mad.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on your original one. A more pythonic one would use for instance, a list comprehension so keep that in mind in the future,

```
output = [numbers[0]]
if len(numbers) >= N:
    for i in range(1,len(numbers)):
        if ((i+1)%N) is 0:
            output.append(numbers[i]*M)
        else:
            output.append(numbers[i]);
else:
    output = numbers
```

If N is not larger than the list size, the program constructs a new list of numbers with each Nth number being multiplied by M. This is done with a simple modulo operator. Indexing in Python starts with zero and i iterates through index values but your desired output counts the elements as if starting from 1 - thus `i+1` in the modulo. If it is not every Nth - program just append the old value. If the list is shorter than N altogether, it assigns the whole unchanged list to the `output` list.

Answer (score 0):

will this work for you?

```
res = []
for num in numbers:
    if num > 0:
        total = num * M
        res.append(total)

if len(res) != len(numbers):
    print (numbers)
else:
    res.reverse()
    print (res)
```

Answer (score 0):

So after many attempts and bouncing this off of a friend who works as a programmer, I ended up with this that gave me the proper output:

```
newlist = []

if len(numbers) < N: 
  newlist = numbers
else: 
  for i in range(0, len(numbers)):
    num = numbers[i]
    if (i+1) % N == 0: 
      newlist.append(num*M)
    else: 
      newlist.append(num)
      i+=1

print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Input
import sys
M= int(sys.argv[2])
N= int(sys.argv[3])

# convert strings to integers
numbers= sys.argv[1].split(',')
for i in range(0, len(numbers)):
  numbers[i]= int(numbers[i])

# if the length of our list is greater than our supplied value
# loop to multiply(starting at the 3rd position in the list) by M
if len(numbers) > N :
  for num in range(2, len(numbers), 3) :
    numbers[num] = numbers[num] * M
print(numbers)
```